# cudaMemset equivalents for non-integer types?

Tags: c++, cuda

I want to use `cudaMemset` for non-integer types to tidy the code as below, where I used the `glm::vec2` type just as an example.
However, `cudaMemset` appears to work only for integers.

So, are there any possible equivalents?

```
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <cuda.h>

int main(){
    glm::vec2* ptr1;
    int num = 10;

    cudaMallocManaged(&ptr1, num*sizeof(glm::vec2));

    cudaMemset(ptr1, {0, 0}, num*sizeof(glm::vec2)); // wish to do sth like this, but it doesn't work
    // for (size_t i = 0; i < num; i++) ptr1[i] = {1, 0}; // want to replace this

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What about `cudaMemset2D` ?

Comment: cudaMemset doesn't work for integer types. Bytes sized values only.

Comment: in addition to the suggestions in the linked duplicate, specifically since you are doing `cudaMallocManaged` here, it should not be necessary to use the CUDA runtime API to initialize the data.  It should be possible to use host methods such as `std::fill`

Comment: float data types are defined in a way that, if all individual bytes are 0, the value is 0.0. For other values: It is quite easy to create a very fast kernel, initializing the memory in parallel.

Comment: @RobertCrovella `std::fill` apparently doesn't work for all types, does it? I got a compile error "error: no instance of overloaded function "std::fill" matches the argument list
            argument types are: (glm::vec2 *, glm::vec2 *, {...})"

Comment: I don't have any trouble using `std::fill` with  a pointer to `glm::vec2`.   See [here](https://pastebin.com/FSQJ5g14). Maybe it doesn't like your initializer.  And yes, there probably are some types that you can't use `std::fill` with.  However `glm::vec2` doesn't appear to be one of them.

Comment: @RobertCrovella You were right. My initialiser was incorrect. Thanks for lettling me know!